# Is there something just like WinMerge only it supports showing all the differences "in one view"?

Tags: windows, source-code, diff, comparison, merge

I use WinMerge all the time, by calling it such as this:

```
winmerge.exe zip1 zip2
```

(Basically.)

That gives me a nice diff of each file inside the both archives, and I can see the changes clearly, just like I want.

... except one small detail: I have to manually click in the left window for each file, and check its differences individually! Especially when I've done a search-and-replace and changed one little minor thing in 500 different source code files, it's a nightmare to manually click through each of these manually. I wish I could just "keep scrolling" past the bottom of the first file view to get to the next one, and so on, until I'm at the bottom.

It seems like a very minor detail, and it is, but that's precisely why it's so frustrating that this is lacking in WinMerge. I've looked all over the program, even asked the authors, but it sadly seems to be another "perpetually dying" software project with little to no new development, or at least not related to this which I'm mentioning.

It's such a shame that it lacks this, because it's increasingly making me find it a chore.

I have tried to manually create my own combined file and diff that, but for complicated and hard-to-describe reasons, this just never works out correctly. It has to be the software building this view, without me creating any extra files inside the archives.

Is there a better WinMerge?